# Tensorflow : dynamically append values to a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have been working with CNN's in Tensorflow and want to keep track of the loss value at every training iteration How can I concatenate values to a tensor at run time with the loss value outputted at every iteration?
Here is a mocked up version of the python code - this throws an error

```
# mocked up example to mimick 4 iterations
sample=[1,2,3,4]
# this is a dummy function to return loss values
def check(x):
 return x*2
# the code below iteratively feeds loss values to concatenate in the loss_list tensor
def tf_check():
    with tf.device(device):
        loss = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
        loss_np = check(loss)
        loss_list = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[])
        
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for t in sample:
            feed_dict = {loss:t}
            y1=sess.run(loss_np,feed_dict)
            loss_list=sess.run(tf.stack([loss_list,y1],axis=0))
tf_check()
```

Comment: Tensorflow 2.4 provides `tf.experimental.numpy.append` to append values dynamically. For more details on the library please refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/experimental/numpy/append). Thanks